# URL Rewrite in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a URL :

```
http://localhost/test/profile?view=trainings&layout=details&id=MjQ1
```

id -> MjQ1 is a record id

i need the Uto be rewritten as :

```
http://localhost/test/profile/trainings/record-title
```

Comment: Is this for a component you wrote or a 3rd party component?

Answer (score 0):

use a a [SEF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef) extension. [sh404SEF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134) is one very good choice and there are others.